# How to set up a SVN without SSH/Shell access?

Tags: ssh, svn, shell

I want to be able to set up a private SVN for my small team that we can share code over the SVN, however I need to enable SSH/Shell access. Is there a way without using SSH/Shell access.

If this is not possible, can I make a HTTP SVN? That lists the files and be able to be checked out by a SVN client, e.g. Cornerstone (for Mac), TortoiseSVN (for PC).

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to used the dav_svn module in Apache. All svn clients support that method and access control is done through simpleauth in Apache and group definitions in dav_svn.

Documentation for it is abundant, here is an example of a quick howto:

http://www.debuntu.org/2006/05/20/54-how-to-subversion-svn-with-apache2-and-dav

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This includes SSH/Shell access?

Comment: Using the dav_svn module and Apache removes the need for ssh/shell access.  A user can connect to the Subversion repository using their SVN client without ssh/shell on the Subversion server.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure quite how to get stuff done, like: `apt-get install subversion libapache2-svn`, I mean where do I put that?

Comment: You need to have administrative access on the box, Apache installed and abasic web server configured. The instructions in the howto explain how to set up a SVN repo in an existing web server config.

Comment: I have my own server with full administrative access, but how do I actually *access* Apache?

Comment: Well... Where would I even begin :) I'm afraid you need to read up on basic administration of Apache and Linux ( I assume you're running Linux?) and this would be beyond the scope of your original question. I can just tell you, that dav_svn under Apache is the answer to your question - many, if not most, SVN servers out there use this method and it is very reliable and performant. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry? Do you even know how to?

Comment: Additionally, please refer to this book: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/ - it has plenty of info about SVN including mod_dav_svn.

Comment: I most definitely know how to, but tutoring you in the basics of Apache web server setup and administration is beyond the scope of your question. You need to study it from the basics and ask questions about specific problems, should they arise - You can't expect people to just guve it to you 100% without knowing anything about your system.

Comment: Well... all I know is that I cannot set up one since I'm using a shared hosting, not yet got a dedicated server. My knowledge in Apache is quite small I agree. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Head over to https://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download and download the subversion binaries for your platform. As part of the install process, you will be asked if you want install Apache and dav_svn as well. Once you do that, you need to configure the Apache server to serve up your subversion repository (once you create it using "svnadmin create", you need to make sure it is owned by the user that runs the Apache server).

Have a look at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html for more information on the Apache configuration.